# How can I display, enable or disable all the Network adapters using PowerShell 5 in windows 7?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am very new to PowerShell. I am using Windows 7 and PowerShell 5.

What I am trying to do is:

1. display all the network adapters for a system.
2. Disable all of them
3. Enable all of them

I am using this code to display all the network adapters:

```
$wmi = get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter
```

This displays all the network adapters and their status.
But the problem is  that, I am not able to disable all pf the network adapters together using this command.

```
$wmi.disable()
```

This statement gives me the error:

```
Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.ManagementObject] does not contain a method named 'disable'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $wmi.disable()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (disable:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Is there any alternative way to display all the network adapters and disable or enable all of them together ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Lachie Thanks for editing all my mistakes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're calling `.disable()` on the *collection* of network adapters and this method only exists for a *single* network adpater.

Try this:

```
$wmi = get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter
$wmi | Foreach-Object {
  Write-Host "Disabling: $($_.name)"
  $_.disable()
}
```